# Getting a key error when trying to print element from a JSON list

Tags: python, json

I have this postcode data I am retrieving from postcodes.io - I am developing some Python code to read this data into a JSON structure.  I then wish to print out just the Country and Region items in this structure.

```js
{                                                                                                                                                                                
  "status": 200,                                                                                                                                                                 
  "result": {                                                                                                                                                                    
    "eastings": 536500,                                                                                                                                                          
    "outcode": "SG8",                                                                                                                                                            
    "admin_county": "Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                                             
    "postcode": "SG8 7XU",                                                                                                                                                       
    "incode": "7XU",                                                                                                                                                             
    "codes": {                                                                                                                                                                   
      "parliamentary_constituency": "E14000845",                                                                                                                                 
      "admin_district": "E07000099",                                                                                                                                             
      "parish": "E04004793",                                                                                                                                                     
      "nuts": "UKH23",                                                                                                                                                           
      "admin_county": "E10000015",                                                                                                                                               
      "ccg": "E38000026",                                                                                                                                                        
      "admin_ward": "E05004782"                                                                                                                                                  
    },                                                                                                                                                                           
    "parliamentary_constituency": "North East Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                    
    "quality": 1,                                                                                                                                                                
    "parish": "Royston",                                                                                                                                                         
    "nuts": "Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                                                     
    "european_electoral_region": "Eastern",                                                                                                                                      
    "latitude": 52.0578463413646,                                                                                                                                                
    "msoa": "North Hertfordshire 002",                                                                                                                                           
    "nhs_ha": "East of England",                                                                                                                                                 
    "primary_care_trust": "Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                                       
    "admin_ward": "Royston Meridian",                                                                                                                                            
    "admin_district": "North Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                                     
    "country": "England",                                                                                                                                                        
    "region": "East of England",                                                                                                                                                 
    "longitude": -0.010476012290143,                                                                                                                                             
    "ccg": "NHS Cambridgeshire and Peterborough",                                                                                                                                
    "lsoa": "North Hertfordshire 002D",                                                                                                                                          
    "northings": 241808                                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import sys  
import json
import urllib

def main(argv):
print ("PCinfo Postcode Search")

# Check program invocation is correct
if len(argv) == 2:
    searchterm = argv[1]
else:
    print("Incorrect program call. Usage: PCinfo.py [POSTCODE]")
    sys.exit(0)

url = 'http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' 
print ("Calling API with URL " + url + searchterm)

try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    url = url + urllib.parse.quote(searchterm)
    response = urlopen(url).readall().decode('utf-8')
    print("I did 3.0 read")
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2
    from urllib import urlopen
    url = url + urllib.quote(searchterm)
    response = urlopen(url).read()
    print("I did 2.0 read")

structure = json.loads(response)
print(json.dumps(structure, indent=2))
print(structure["country"])


if __name__== "__main__":
    from sys import argv
    main(argv)
```

Here is the output from the program.  The first print works fine and displays the entire JSON list but I get "Key Error" when trying to print out just country?  Spent hours looking at it! Please help!

```
sh-4.4$ python PCinfo7.py SG87XU                                                                                                                                                 
PCinfo Postcode Search                                                                                                                                                           
Calling API with URL http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/SG87XU                                                                                                                    
I did 2.0 read                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                
  "status": 200,                                                                                                                                                                 
  "result": {                                                                                                                                                                    
    "eastings": 536500,                                                                                                                                                          
    "outcode": "SG8",                                                                                                                                                            
    "admin_county": "Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                                             
    "postcode": "SG8 7XU",                                                                                                                                                       
    "incode": "7XU",                                                                                                                                                             
    "codes": {                                                                                                                                                                   
      "parliamentary_constituency": "E14000845",                                                                                                                                 
      "admin_district": "E07000099",                                                                                                                                             
      "parish": "E04004793",                                                                                                                                                     
      "nuts": "UKH23",                                                                                                                                                           
      "admin_county": "E10000015",                                                                                                                                               
      "ccg": "E38000026",                                                                                                                                                        
      "admin_ward": "E05004782"                                                                                                                                                  
    },                                                                                                                                                                           
    "parliamentary_constituency": "North East Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                    
    "quality": 1,                                                                                                                                                                
    "parish": "Royston",                                                                                                                                                         
    "nuts": "Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                                                     
    "european_electoral_region": "Eastern",                                                                                                                                      
    "latitude": 52.0578463413646,                                                                                                                                                
    "msoa": "North Hertfordshire 002",                                                                                                                                           
    "nhs_ha": "East of England",                                                                                                                                                 
    "primary_care_trust": "Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                                       
    "admin_ward": "Royston Meridian",                                                                                                                                            
    "admin_district": "North Hertfordshire",                                                                                                                                     
    "country": "England",                                                                                                                                                        
    "region": "East of England",                                                                                                                                                 
    "longitude": -0.010476012290143,                                                                                                                                             
    "ccg": "NHS Cambridgeshire and Peterborough",                                                                                                                                
    "lsoa": "North Hertfordshire 002D",                                                                                                                                          
    "northings": 241808                                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                               
  File "PCinfo7.py", line 45, in <module>                                                                                                                                        
    main(argv)                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "PCinfo7.py", line 40, in main                                                                                                                                            
    print(structure["country"])
```

Comment: Perhaps try changing `json.loads(response)` to `response.json()`?

Comment: What about `print(structure["result"]["country"])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `country` doesn't exist within the `structure` json.

`structure` has `result` which in turn contains `country`

access it using

```
print(structure['result']['country'])
```

Comment: Yes that worked a treat, thanks very much for your help my friend!

Comment: when figuring out `json` or `dict` types, paying attention to the brackets help

Comment: On the off-chance your structure might occasionally be missing the "country" key, you might consider something like the following:
`     try:
         print (structure["result"]["country"])
     except KeyError: 
     # If you want notice
         print("NO COUNTRY LISTED")
     # or If you don't care
         pass`

Comment: @FrustratedCoder Cheers!